# How can I replace this shell script?

Tags: perl, bash, shell, awk, zsh

I have the following Z shell script to launch an instance of a program if one is not already actively running, even if there is a zombie instance, or to resume a stopped instance. I feel like there must be a better way to do this using, maybe using perl. The shell script just seems too awkward - at least it should be possible to to the text manipulation from another language, like perl or awk.

```
launchprogram(){
if [ $# = 0 ]
then
    cat <<\EOF
launchprogram requires at least one argument.
Usage: launchprogram <program> <optional arguments>
EOF
    return 1
fi
mystatus=Z # assume we have a zombie process
process="$(pgrep "$1" | tr \\n ,)"
echo "$process"
process="${process%,}"
if [ "$process" != '' ]
then
        process="$(ps -o 'pid s cmd' -p "$process" | sed '1 d')"
fi
oldifs="$IFS"
IFS="$(printf \nX)"
IFS="${IFS%X}"
for i in $process
do
    mystatus="${process[2]}"
    case $mystatus in
    (T)
        if ! kill -CONT "${i[1]}"
        then
        IFS="$oldifs"
        return $?
        fi
        ;;
    (Z)
        ;;
    (*)
        IFS="$oldifs"
        return $?
        ;;
    esac
done
IFS="$oldifs"
    setopt nobgnice
"$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &!
unsetopt nobgnice
}
```

Comment: Probably it's better to not do any text manipulation at all, but use the CPAN module `Proc::ProcessTable`.

Comment: Show some sample input and expected output for the part you want to replace (i.e. for your desired awk script).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see what you should replace with awk/perl/…, but this script seems not to work:

1. Two lines with IFS produce IFS equal to `n` while expected IFS that contains only newline.
2. `"$process[2]"` is not correct because it is the second character and not the second column. Not mentioning that it was `$i[2]` that was meant.
3. Same for `${i[1]}`.
4. By default in zsh variables are not automatically splitted into arguments, thus `for i in $process` will always iterate over one value: the whole `$process`.

Thus I would rewrite the script using the following considerations:

1. `pgrep` is not needed since `ps` supports `-C` (this assumes program name does not contain spaces or commas). Neither `sed` is needed since there is way to remove the header.
2. zsh has `${(f)}` for those who need to split strings by lines. And `${(s. .)}` for splitting by spaces.
3. Last (`cmd`) column is not used anywhere.
4. `mystatus` does not need default as it is not used anywhere outside of the cycle.

```
launchprogram(){
    emulate -L zsh
    if [ $# = 0 ]
    then
        cat  
EOF
        return 1
    fi
    local mystatus
    local process
    local i
    local -a iarr
    process="$(ps -o 'pid=,s=' -C "$1")"
    echo "$process"
    for i in ${(f)process}
    do
        iarr=( ${(s. .)i} )
        mystatus="${iarr[2]}"
        case $mystatus in
            (T)
                if ! kill -CONT "${iarr[1]}"
                then
                    return $?
                fi
                ;;
            (Z)
                ;;
            (*)
                return $?
                ;;
        esac
    done
    setopt nobgnice
    "$@" >/dev/null 2>&1 &!
    # With emulate -L unsetting option is not needed
}
```